# why "%d" is wrong in OCaml scanf format?

Tags: ocaml

when I implement read_int function with ocaml (see below),

```
let read_int () = Scanf.bscanf Scanf.Scanning.stdin "%d" (fun x -> x)
```

if the format argument is `%d`(no space) , the compiler will return failure with the following information:

```
Exception:
Scanf.Scan_failure
"scanf: bad input at char number 1: ``character '\\n' is not a decimal digit''".
```

but if I use `' '%d`(prefix with space), it is fine, why `%d` is wrong?  what is the difference between `%d` and `' '%d`? . thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scanf` format `"%d"` matches a string of decimal digits. This doesn't include white space. In a `scanf` format string a space (`" "`) stands for any amount of white space (spaces, tabs, newlines).

It's not really possible to tell exactly what else is going on, because I don't know what appears on the standard input of your program. Possibly the problem is the `'\n'` that appears at the end of the previous line.

**Update**: For what it's worth, I decided long ago (in my C programming days) that `scanf` causes more problems than it solves. It's particularly bad at handling lines of input. Better to break input into lines by another method and use `sscanf` (or `int_of_string`) on the resulting strings.

Comment: Thank you very much, I see, I think we should always use " %d " instead of "%d" to prevent potential error.

Comment: I personally tend to avoid scanf completely, and go for real lexing (ie ocamllex or the like). The code usually gets simpler to understand, manipulate, extend, and should not be significantly slower than lexing by hand.

Comment: Absolutely, I tend to use `scanf` only for quick tests that I intend to throw away later. It's a great idea to have an inverse of `printf` but it works out surprisingly badly in practice.